# Can't use Reuxable inc.xaml theme

Tags: wpf, themes

Has someone used reuxable free themes, specially the "inc.xaml"? If yes, can you help me with this? The sample I downloaded from nukeation is using `mercury.xaml` and it works fine, but when I change to inc.xaml, I got some errors. The problem is that the compiler does not recognize the style named 'incbutton'. Below is the code I have:

```
<!--App.xaml-->
<Application
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
x:Class="GeminiSampleProject.App"
StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <!-- Resources scoped at the Application level should be defined here. -->
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/ReuxablesLegacy;component/inc.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

```
//fragment of code that fire error
<Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Margin="33,16.08,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="80" Style="{StaticResource IncButton}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I think it is that the Static Resource "IncButton" does not exist in inc.xml but it exist in mercery.xml.

My problem was the same but another static resource and i checked in the .dll file and find out that the resource only existed in mercery but not in inc.

br/
J